# Apache basic HTTP authentication not working

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess, http-basic-authentication, .htpasswd

Trying to setup basic HTTP authentication with Apache, but it's not working. I get the directory listing and files regularly, no authentication required. I tried restarting httpd and the browsers cache.

I can't find any relevant entries in /var/log/httpd/error_log.

Any ideas?

**htpasswd:**

```
# htpasswd -c /usr/local/share/passwords username
$ ls -l /usr/local/share/passwords 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 44 Nov 23 13:29 /usr/local/share/passwords
```

**.htaccess:**

```
$ cat /srv/http/test/.htaccess 
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Some Stuff"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/share/passwords
Require user username
```

**The directory:**

```
$ ls -la /srv/http/test/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 23 13:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 23 00:40 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   96 Nov 23 13:35 .htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Nov 23 00:40 page.html
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work ? Any relevant entries in your error log file ?

Comment: Updated the post with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to overwrite authentication settings using htaccess files?
See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: Please point people at the correct documentation! `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride`

Answer (score 0):

Have you allowed overrides in your apache config? 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

(Sorry for old link. If you are using an older version of apache then replace 'current' with the version you are using, eg 2.0, etc)

Comment: Please point people at the correct documentation! `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html`